# The seventh parameter passed to add_submenu_page()

Tags: theme-development, errors, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

I'm testing WordPress 5.3 (*5.3-RC4-46673*) with my theme. I have `WP_DEBUG` enabled. I notice the following error in the dashboard now:

> Notice: add_submenu_page was called incorrectly. The seventh parameter passed to add_submenu_page() should be an integer representing menu position. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 5.3.0.) in /app/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4903

There's a related ticket for this error here: [Trac Ticket #48249](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48249)

**Troubleshooting**
The theme I'm using is a child theme.

- Disabled all plugins, issue persists.
- Issue happens with child them active and parent theme active.
- Issue goes away with twentynineteen.

So it's definitely within the theme. Just not sure how to go about tracking this down.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the issue is there even when the active theme is the parent theme. That means the parent theme is creating a submenu page with a wrong argument, probably due to the confusion between add_menu_page and add_submenu_page.

The best course of action would be to contact the author of the parent theme, so that he can patch it.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to track this down to the culprit function `add_theme_page()`. There

There was an additional parameter, per [the codex for add_theme_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_page/) that needed to be removed. Removing that seemed to help.

```
function fivehundred_register_admin_menu() {
  add_theme_page(
    '500 Settings',
    '500 Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'theme-settings',
    'fivehundred_admin_menu',
    plugins_url( '/ignitiondeck/images/ignitiondeck-menu.png' )
  );
}

add_action(
  'admin_menu',
  'fivehundred_register_admin_menu'
);
```

Fixed code

```
function fivehundred_register_admin_menu() {
  add_theme_page(
    '500 Settings',
    '500 Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'theme-settings',
    'fivehundred_admin_menu'
  );
}

add_action(
  'admin_menu',
  'fivehundred_register_admin_menu'
);
```

Comment: same with [`add_dashboard_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_dashboard_page/) the icon parameter changes to menu position ( def: null )

Answer (score 1):

This Notice can be triggered by several variations/wrappers of the function `add_submenu_page`.

as of WP v5.8

- add_plugins_page
- add_users_page
- add_dashboard_page
- add_posts_page
- add_media_page
- add_links_page
- add_pages_page
- add_comments_page
- add_management_page
- add_options_page
- add_theme_page

To narrow the scope looking for the right function, we can modify the core file `./wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` ( around line 1420 ) to be more verbose about it.

```
_doing_it_wrong(
  __FUNCTION__,
  sprintf(
    /* translators: %s: add_submenu_page() */
    __( 'The seventh parameter passed to %s should be an integer representing menu position. %s' ),
    '<code>add_submenu_page()</code>',
    print_r( $new_sub_menu, true )
  ),
  '5.3.0'
);
```

In my case the offending function was `add_dashboard_page`

```
add_dashboard_page(
  'Link Builder',
  'Link Builder',
  'manage_options',
  'mytheme-woocommerce-helper',
  array( $this, 'mytheme_woocommerce_helper_create_admin_page' ),
  'dashicons-admin-generic',
  2
);
```

Notice before edit core file:

```
PHP Notice:  add_submenu_page was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. 
The seventh parameter passed to <code>add_submenu_page()</code> 
should be an integer representing menu position.  
Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. 
(This message was added in version 5.3.0.) in wp-includes/functions.php on line 5535
```

Notice after edit core file:

```
PHP Notice:  add_submenu_page was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. 
The seventh parameter passed to <code>add_submenu_page()</code> 
should be an integer representing menu position.  
Array
(
   [0] => Link Builder
   [1] => manage_options
   [2] => mytheme-woocommerce-helper
   [3] => Link Builder
)
```

**warning/disclaimer/notes**

Do this edit only in a development instance. WP core updates or upgrades will revert the changes. Plugins like wordfence will emit a warning and maybe revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the warning by adding the seventh parameter as `null`.

```
function fivehundred_register_admin_menu() {
  add_theme_page(
    '500 Settings',
    '500 Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'theme-settings',
    'fivehundred_admin_menu',
    plugins_url( '/ignitiondeck/images/ignitiondeck-menu.png' ),
    null
  );
}

add_action(
  'admin_menu',
  'fivehundred_register_admin_menu'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

*This same error is also being applied to argument issues in the add_pages_page() function.*

For anyone else not using add_theme_page() or add_submenu_page() functions look for your usage of add_pages_page() and correct the arguments.

In my case I needed to remove the first argument which was null and give the page a title.